# How can I label points in this graphic of simulation of extinction?

Tags: r

Can you help me on putting labels on the following graph:

[image]

The code I use:

```
ext <- read.table("C:/Users/AngieLee/Dropbox/TESIS/total_ex.txt", header=T, sep="\t", row.names=1, dec=",", na.strings="NA")

#total_ex.txt is a adjacency matrix with birds species in the columns and plant species in the rows.

ex<-second.extinct(ext, 
           participant="higher",
           method="degree",
           details="FALSE",
           nrep=50,
           ext.row=NULL, 
           ext.col=NULL)

slope.bipartite(ex, plot.it=TRUE, ann=FALSE)
```

With this code I obtain the graph that I attach.

In this link you can find the matrix that I use:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfu6m3bvkdwrjq9/total_ex.csv?dl=0

The package that I used is Bipartite.

Comment: where are your functions second.extinct and slope.bipartite defined?

Comment: They are functions of the package Bipartite.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bipartite/bipartite.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
slope.bipartite(ex, plot.it=TRUE, ann=TRUE)
if (all(ex[-nrow(ex), 2] == 1)) {
  y <- -ex[, 3]
} else {
  y <- -ex[, 2]
}
y <- (sum(y) - cumsum(y))/sum(y)
x <- (ex[, "no"]/max(ex[, "no"]))
text(x,y-0.02,labels=names(y), cex=0.5)
```

[image]